# File from Assets: com.itextpdf.io.exceptions.IOException: PDF header not found

Tags: android, kotlin, itext

I have a problem with `itext` when I want to fill out a pdf form.
I store the pdf form in the assets folder, then I create a `PdfReader` and a `PdfWriter` as follows:

```
val am: AssetManager = this.assets
val src: InputStream = am.open("valoracion_01.pdf")

val reader = PdfReader(src)
val destination = PdfWriter(dest)

val pdfDoc = PdfDocument(reader,destination)
```

I have a problem with creating the reader.

```
PdfReader(src)---> com.itextpdf.io.exceptions.IOException: PDF header not found.
```

I want to include the PDF form in my data folder instead of storage in the SD card or internal memory.  But it seems `itext` can't open that file to fill it with the data.

What do you think?

Comment: Have you checked what your `src` input stream really contains?

Comment: If I do src.read() result is 37 so it is not empty....  And this file is he same I use on a different version of the app with itext,.

Comment: *"If I do src.read() result is 37 so it is not empty"* - but what do you actually retrieve from `src`? E.g. share the first 100 bytes you get.